# Propagating asynchronously calculated data back to the GUI thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I implemented a service that asynchronously fetches data from an eyetracker and provides a PublishSubject that anyone who is interested can subscribe to to get a stream of the latest eyetracking events.

What i have no clue about is how to get these events into my GUI thread (since eyetracking is pretty useless without the information of what is being displayed) and how to throttle the received events enough so the GUI does not lag because of blocking the thread.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do that using RxJava?

Comment: Basic UI design is to have a background thread to do processing and the UI thread pick up the updates

Comment: You have to give more information about technology: is it an Swing app? javafx? or android?

Comment: JavaFX would probably be the one that gets used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive extensions offer something called ***Schedulers***. They instruct a stream to change threads on which they either produce or observe items. You can set them through operators `subscribeOn`, which modifies the stream so that your producer emits its items ( in other words, calls `onNext` method on its subscribers ), or through operator called `observeOn` which tells the stream to schedule its observing work on specified scheduler.

```
getSomeObservable() // Observable does its work on computation scheduler
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // instructs to switch every afterwards operator to observe items on io scheduler
    .map(...) // this callback is called on a thread provided by io scheduler
    .filter(...) // and this as well
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // switch to new thread scheduler
    .doOnNext() // new thread
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // instructs to produce items on computational scheduler
    .subscribe(...) // still scheduling this task to new thread scheduler
```

Usually frameworks with some level of support for rx have some Scheduler implementation that performs work on UI thread ... Android for example has a library which provides `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` which is exactly what you are looking for, only in your framework

Answer (score 0):

> ... You can move computations or blocking IO to some other thread via
>   subscribeOn. Once the data is ready, you can make sure they get
>   processed on the foreground or GUI thread via observeOn